# android how can i open ADW launcher from my activity

Tags: java, android, launcher

i have theme and i want to put activity so when user open it he will see some thing like that[image]

i want to know what the action or package name i should provide to open ADW launcher

**ANSWER**

OK i found the solution
 Intent i=new Intent("org.adw.launcher.SET_THEME"); 
it will open adw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and most likely you can check the package name on /data/app/ folder

Comment: like I said you can check it on the /data/app/ folder, easiest thing would be doing an ls (getting list of files/folder in that folder)